# Avoiding the Base href tag on an ASP.NET Button

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a website that uses the base href tag, but I'm currently working on a web page on the localhost and when I click an asp button, it tries to resolve to the basehref/mynewpage. How can, for testing purposes, I avoid using the base href just in the case of my button, so that when I click the button it reloads the localhost base instead of the actual url?

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do?  Instead of:  href=http://localhost/mypage.html use: href="/mypage.html" ?

Comment: I don't think that's quite it. I have a button and when I click it, it resolves to the base href, so it goes to mysite.com/test.aspx, because the base href of the webpage is mysite.com/. What I would like this particular button to do, is go to localhost/###/test.aspx instead

Comment: oooooh, i get it - it took me a bit to figure that one out too. In visual studio, stop the project and in the solutions expolorer click on the root folter of your site (ie: http://www.mysite.com) lookk in the properties folder, there's a setting for "Virtual Path" that usually defaults to "/Website1" or whatever your project is called.  Replace it with "/" and you're good to go.

Comment: @Losebear You should create an answer from this, Losbear.

Comment: Hm I know I'm close and just missing something stupid. The virtual Path is only available when using Visual Studio Development Server, and it was defaulted as /. When changing from using the Local IIS Server, it still didn't seem to work regardless of having the / as the virtual path.

Comment: Humm, maybe just for testing purposes you can change the HOSTS file to resolve the path to your local webserver. No, never mind... you might need access to the real website at times.